# Input se limpando automaticamente

Tags: php, jquery

estou criando um chat porem o input onde se escreve a mensagem se autolimpa antes mesmo de enviar a mensagem segue o codigo para me darem uma mão do que possa ser, se caso precisarem de mais detalhes posto o codigo completo

script

```
   $(function() {
afficheConversation();
$('#envoyer').click(function() {
    var nom = $('#nom').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.post('chat.php', {'nom':nom, 'message': message }, function() {
      afficheConversation;
    });
});

function afficheConversation() {
  $('#conversation').load('chatlog.htm');
  $('#message').val('');
  $('#message').focus();
}
setInterval(afficheConversation, 3000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

resolvido o problema era que eu estava colocando o $('#message').val(''); na parte onde fazia o refresh alterei para logo apos que enviei o post e deu certo. OBS: coisas de novatos nao manjo de jquery

```
$(function() {
afficheConversation();
$('#envoyer').click(function() {
    var nom = $('#nom').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.post('chat.php', {'nom':nom, 'message': message }, function() {
      afficheConversation;
    $('#message').val('');
    });
});

function afficheConversation() {
  $('#conversation').load('chatlog.htm');
  $('#message').focus();
}
setInterval(afficheConversation, 3000);
});
```